# ¿Es posible insertar el iframe de un mapa de google maps?

Tags: php, google-maps

Estoy creando una herramienta en donde se le da la posibilidad a los usuarios de insertar en un campo de texto el iframe de google maps, es decir, esto:

```
<iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d481728.80462972773!2d-99.42381643176068!3d19.390519022922902!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x85ce0026db097507%3A0x54061076265ee841!2sCiudad+de+M%C3%A9xico%2C+CDMX!5e0!3m2!1ses-419!2smx!4v1545444246303" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

Sin embargo, muchos usuarios no insertan el iframe como tal, insertan la URL completa, algo así:

https://www.google.com.mx/maps/place/Ciudad+de+M%C3%A9xico,+CDMX/@19.390519,-99.4238164,10z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m5!3m4!1s0x85ce0026db097507:0x54061076265ee841!8m2!3d19.4326077!4d-99.133208

Me gustaría saber si existe alguna manera de abrir el mapa en un modal de boostrap y desde ahí obtener el iframe de dicho mapa, o por lo menos las coordenadas para construir dicho iframe, o algo por el estilo que evite que los usuarios salgan del panel de control, hagan la búsqueda en google e inserten otros datos que no son los esperados.

He buscado en la documentación de google maps, pero me temo que hay que pagar por hacer uso por la API de google :(

El proyecto está en php y jquery.

Gracias por la info.

Answer (score 1):

Podes utilizar google maps mediante la api de maps

```
<iframe
  width="600"
  height="450"
  frameborder="0" style="border:0"
  src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=YOUR_API_KEY
    &q=Space+Needle,Seattle+WA" allowfullscreen>
</iframe>
```

[Documentacion iframe google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/guide)

[Crear api en google maps](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/get-api-key)